# amcharts assigning unique keys as field

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to use amcharts to display some data.
I have some json data in this format from a url:

```
    var jsondata = {
      "name1" : {
        "key1": 5,
        "key2": "value1",
        "data": {
            "data1": {
                "field1": 2,
                "field2": 3,
                "field3": 4
            }
        }
      },
      "name2" : {
        "key1": 5,
        "key2": "value1",
        "data": {
            "data2": {
                "field1": 2,
                "field2": 3,     
            },
            "data3": {
                "field1": 2,
                "field2": 3,     
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

In one instance using the name key as x axis and key1 as y. 
In another using data1/2/3 as x and its fields as needed.

However name1/name2 and data1/data2/data3 in this example are unique/dynamically generated.

I'm unsure with javascript if there is an easy way to reference these keys or if I am best to present the data in another way to make it more easily accessible ?
If so how would you best represent the data in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amCharts requires a `dataProvider` in a certain format. The format is always like this:

```
[{
  "category": "Company A",
  "value": 100
}, {
  "category": "Company B",
  "value": 200
}, {
  // etc ...
}]
```

You can use different key names for `category` and `value`, but dataProvider should always be an array of objects.

You can convert your jsondata to this format. It is quite straightforward. Assuming that **name1** and **name2** keys are actually the categories:

```
var my_dataprovider = [];

for(category in jsondata){

  my_dataprovider.push({
    "category": category,
    "key1": jsondata[category].key1,
    "key2": jsondata[category].key2
  });

}
```

If you also require the nested fields to be accessible for amCharts, I would "flatten" them:

```
var my_dataprovider = [];

for(category in jsondata){

  var data_item = {
    "category": category,
    "key1": jsondata[category].key1,
    "key2": jsondata[category].key2
  };

  // flatten nested fields (inside "data")
  for(key in jsondata[category].data){
    // data1... or data2, data3...
    for(field in jsondata[category].data[key]){
      // field1, field2...
      data_item[key + '_' + field] = jsondata[category].data[key][field];
    }
  }

  /*
    {
      "category": "name1",
      "key1": 5,
      "key2": "value1",
      "data1_field1": 2,
      "data1_field2": 3,
      "data1_field3": 4
    }
  */

  my_dataprovider.push(data_item);

}
```

You can set your amCharts graph's `valueField` to one of the keys inside your dataProvider.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": my_dataprovider,
  "categoryField": "category",
  "graphs": [{
    // ...
    "valueField": "data1_field1"
  }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed to get it to work.